# Dropwizard 0.8.0 static content request logging

Tags: logging, static, dropwizard

My Dropwizard (0.8.0) logging configuration is as below and working as expected:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    com.netflix.config: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: WARN
  appenders:
    - type: console
```

which correctly produces log output formatted similar to the below, as expected:

```
17:24:22 server.1 | INFO  [2015-04-09 16:24:22,558] com.blah.Resource: blah b.
17:33:08 server.1 | DEBUG [2015-04-09 16:33:08,396] com.netflix.config.AbstractPollingScheduler: Polling started
```

However, having integrated with the [dropwizard-swagger](https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger) project, I can now see log statements for static resources such as:

```
17:26:26 server.1 | 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Apr/2015:16:26:26 +0000] "GET /api-docs/config-service HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://localhost:8443/swagger" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36" 11
```

which clearly isn't conforming to the same / intended format.

How do I control the logging of these static resources? I'd actually like to turn them off, but can't see anything in the Dropwizard docs about logging static content requests.

Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those logs are the request logs which are generated at Jetty level. It doesn't matter whether they are static resources or jersey resources, or even a resource that doesn't exist; dropwizard will log them in its own format. You can debug and see them on [Slf4jRequestLog class](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/2655ac703a0f6ddb4eae933a74dae3d12fde287f/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/Slf4jRequestLog.java).

I don't know to what extent you can manipulate it; but in the [documentation](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#request-log) in ***Configuration Reference*** section, it says you can change the appender format. I don't think that will let you turn off logging certain URIs. A more advanced thing to do would be to inherit [RequestLogFactory class](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/2655ac703a0f6ddb4eae933a74dae3d12fde287f/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/RequestLogFactory.java), change whatever you want manually and assign it to configuration at [AbstractServerFactory](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/483425cbe47222b6ad54d2f5a5120c2cfc9f8222/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/AbstractServerFactory.java).

Comment: Thanks @Natan. 

The RequestLogFactory#appenders by default only contains a ConsoleAppenderFactory so these log statements no longer appear once I start logging to a file appender (or wherever). 

So not actually going to be a problem once in a production-like environment.

Many thanks, Andrew